# What words do you use to describe a good arguer?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call a person who makes very good arguments in a debate or in a general discussion?

Comment: Verbally strong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rhetoricians** will always have good arguments to bear them out.

> **rhetorician**
>
> - a person who is good at speaking in public, especially someone who is able to influence people. -  [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rhetorician)
> - someone who speaks and writes effectively, especially someone who is able to persuade or influence people. [MD](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/rhetorician)

Examples in the literature:

1. "...description of [a rhetorician](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=J2ldWwIQhHwC&pg=PA207&dq=%22a+rhetorician%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIw-TB_LHOAhXFxpAKHccWCCUQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22a%20rhetorician%22&f=false) as someone whose appeals are limited to rational argument."
2. "[And I say that if a rhetorician and a physician](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=g6RjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22a+rhetorician%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4luWc_bHOAhWCx5AKHYbrCNk4FBDoAQhAMAU#v=onepage&q=%22a%20rhetorician%22&f=false) were to go to any city, and had there to argue in the Ecclesia or any other assembly as to which of them should be elected state-physician, the physician would have no chance."

Comment: But a rhetorician is someone who is good at public speaking.What if it is someone who doesn't speak well in public but is generally good with arguments among friends.

Comment: @VisnuGanth  good with arguments....  usually but not necessarily in public.  A rhetorician will be a good arguer anywhere, anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I shall go with **ARTICULATE** as the proper word.
Based on the following description.

"expressing yourself easily or characterized by clear expressive language
“articulate speech”
“an articulate orator”
“articulate beings”
Synonyms:
eloquent, facile, fluent, silver, silver-tongued, smooth-spoken
expressing yourself readily, clearly, effectively." Please see https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/articulate

Comment: _Articulate_ is a very reasonable suggestion, in my opinion—but as an answer it isn't much good to anyone who doesn't already know the sense of the word you have in mind. A complete answer would include a relevant definition of the word _articulate_, along with a citation of the dictionary from which that definition came. Please consider adding this elements to your answer.